# How do you calculate the random variable probability?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

"According to the Census Bureau, $13\%$ of American adults (aged 18 and over) are Hispanic. An opinion poll plans to contact an SRS of $1200$ adults. Should we be suspicious if the sample selected for the opinion poll contains $15\%$  Hispanic people? Compute an appropriate probability to support your answer."

The answer stated in the textbook to this question is $P(x≥180)$ and then goes on to fully solve the question, for a final value of $0.0235$. However, I am confused at why it would not be $P(x=180)$. Please help!

Comment: What's left unstated/ambiguous is that "contains" means "has as part of its sample at least."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the question is asking how rare it is that there are 15% or more Hispanic people instead of exactly 15% Hispanic people.